# ios view transitions animations, page curl

Tags: iphone

i'm new to the ios sdk and i'm developing my first app. i need to implement a curl transition between multiple views; giving the user the impression they are reading a book. the documentation only talks about doing it between two views in a single view controller. like i said i need to implement this with a stack of several views. do i need to use more than 1 view controller? if so how? or do i have to use 1 view controller but use say 10 views in a stack? again how would i go about doing this.

would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use only two views for this:  one for the view being animated (to an offscreen position), and one for the view underneath.  To handle multiple flips, you would animate the top view to its offscreen position, then fill it with the data for the page underneath the current page and then insert it underneath the current page.  For the subsequent flip, you would animate the current off the screen, etc.

You could alternatively use a number of views that matches the total number of pages you want to display.  This might make your coding simpler, but it would eat up a lot more memory.